# subprocess in python 2.7 send input

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I've successfully piped the output and input from a separate python script called from popen subprocess in python 3.4, change raw_input to input but it must work in a 2.7 environment. Currently no output is displayed when working in 2.7. How can i get this tow work for 2.7?

test.py:

```
import threading
import subprocess

def read_output(process):
    print("starting to read")
    for line in process.stdout:
       print (line.rstrip().decode('utf-8'))


process = subprocess.Popen('python test2.py', shell=False,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=None)

# Create new thread: pass target and argument
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=read_output,args=(process,))

# Start new Threads
thread1.daemon=True
thread1.start()

s=input("")

process.stdin.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
process.stdin.write("\r\n".encode('utf-8'))
process.stdin.flush()  # close standard input or thread doesn't terminate

thread1.join()
```

simple test script test2.py:

```
print("running script 2")
print("Enter an input A,B,C:")

s=raw_input("")
print("you selected:"+s)
```

Comment: You have to write something in process.stdin then flush it.

Comment: I do that in two locations, where are you saying it should be present?

Comment: I misread. Should work OK (well, I don't get why you send 2 strings, whereas the test program only accepts one and exits). maybe you have to `sys.stdout.flush()` as well in the `test2.py` script.

Comment: I originally had a longer test script. The end goal is to not have control over the test script it is not feasible to modify it.